# What does {} do in MySQL queries?

Tags: php, mysql

I tried this Google query but it didn't show up (possibly because { was parsed as some special character or ignored).

I saw a query made on an example somewhere that looks like this:

```sql
SELECT `id` FROM areas WHERE `name` = '{$listing['cityname']}'
```

And this was in PHP (so inside `mysql_query()`)

My best guess is it searches as a Lowercase (same as `LOWER(`name`) AS...`) but I want to be 100% sure how that's supposed to work.

Comment: It has to do with "injection attacks". Parameters, please! (Also, include the *full* minimal-context of the code, as it will make the question and answer(s) more useful for people in the future :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's PHP syntax, not MySQL syntax. It allows you to interpolate [complex expressions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) in a double-quoted string. So in your example, the array index `$listing['cityname']` will be evaluated, and its value used in your query.

It has nothing to do with SQL whatsoever.

By the way, that's a gaping SQL injection vulnerability, assuming the array value hasn't yet been escaped with something like `mysql_real_escape_string()`. Most people use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) for building SQL queries these days.

Comment: What would be an example of such interpolation? Can you give a short example please. Thanks.

Comment: Yup but this is purely an internal process within my cron job so security is not an issue in this case. All other sections with user input has the mysql_real_escape_string() function.

Comment: I read through the examples and I don't understand the difference between this and, say, $sql = "SELECT `id` FROM areas WHERE `name` = ' ".$listing['cityname']." ' ";

Comment: @jeffkee: There's no difference. At that point it's simply a matter of whichever looks nicer to you :)

Comment: You are a saint @BoltClock This was driving me nuts!